# Unable to use SaveAndPublish from ContentService

Tags: umbraco, umbraco8

I'm trying to save my `IContent` called `child`, but on this line(`contentService.SaveAndPublish(child);`) I get the following error: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

```
if (child.HasProperty("navn"))
{
    child.SetValue("navn", worker.Name.ToString(), "da-dk");
}
contentService.SaveAndPublish(child);
```

This is how I define my `contentService`:
`IContentService contentService = Umbraco.Core.Composing.Current.Services.ContentService;`

And I'm finding the children like this:

```
long totalChildren;

IEnumerable<IContent> children = contentService.GetPagedChildren(filialsParent.Id, 0, 100, out totalChildren);
```

´
Can someone point out what is wrong here?

Comment: Tried following - https://cultiv.nl/blog/using-hangfire-for-scheduled-tasks-in-umbraco/ ?

Comment: Maybe there's an event listener subscribed to Publishing with some code that's breaking your data after it's been saved but before it's published.[https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/reference/events/contentservice-events](https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/reference/events/contentservice-events). Even if that's not the problem you could make an event listener for the publishing event and see if your data is making it that far or not.

Comment: @Matt Yes that is the guide i follow, note that the error has nothing to do with hangfire

Comment: I think it maybe due to Umbraco.Core.Composing.Current been null. Not done any v8 but in 7 the applicationContext would be null.

Comment: @Matt Thanks for your comment, I haven't tested it yet, but do you have an idea how to fix it.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I don't unfortunately there is a really good thread on the community forums about this process though - https://our.umbraco.com/forum/umbraco-8/95966-umbraco-8-and-hangfire

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found out that if I do this then it works.

```
var umbf = Umbraco.Web.Composing.Current.Factory.GetInstance<IUmbracoContextFactory>();
using (var contextf = umbf.EnsureUmbracoContext())
{
    var umbcontext = contextf.UmbracoContext;
    IContentService cs = Umbraco.Core.Composing.Current.Services.ContentService;
    cs.SaveAndPublish(child);

}
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe you're getting your ContentService the wrong way and therefore it may be empty, causing a null reference exception.

If you're in a SurfaceController, you can get ContentService like this:

```
var cs = Services.ContentService;
```

If you're in a class where Services is not exposed, you can get it like this:

```
var cs = ApplicationContext.Current.Services.ContentService;
```

Read more about it in Umbracos documentation below :)

https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/Reference/Management/Services/ContentService/

Comment: In C# with Umbraco 8, there is no ApplicationContext to be found.

Comment: Ah, my bad. What about going with a dependency injection approach? Inject ContentService into the controller and pass it to your class library?

Comment: Im not using this code in any controllers. This code runs along with Hangfire as a schedule task every hour.

Comment: Ah. This is my last guess, maybe this can help you: https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/Getting-Started/Code/Umbraco-Services/

Comment: thanks but I've already got the content service, and that is working, its only the SaveAndPublish() that dont work... `.Save()` works just fine.

Comment: I'll award you the bounty since you were the first to answer and also you tried a lot to help me.

Answer (score 0):

Look [that link](https://our.umbraco.com/forum/extending-umbraco-and-using-the-api/77419-contentservice-saveandpublish-throwing-objectreference-exception), seems that Umbraco 'Save' works even if something is null but not completely:

> Save is working but not completely, it is saving the content to the db
>   but not to the Umbraco backoffice. And even when I try wrapping the
>   setValues inside a
>
> `if (blogNode.HasProperty("title")) {`
>
> I still get a null reference
>   error.

In the OP case he's taking the wrong contentService in the first step, so i think @Mikkel answer is not completely wrong:

> Turns out I had used the wrong parentId in this line:
>
> `var newBlog = contentService.CreateContent(post.Title, 1053, "umbNewsItem", 0);`
>
> the correct statement was:
>
> `var newBlog = contentService.CreateContent(post.Title, 1061, "umbNewsItem", 0);`

L-

Comment: Legion, Im not using CreateContent because it already exists. The `child` comes from `children` if you look at my post

Comment: What i mean is, check that the context that already exist is the correct context/is not null. Because that's exactly your problem.

Umbraco.Core.Composing.Current.Services.ContentService; is probably null, that's the problem.

Comment: The content service was not null I can tell you.

Comment: i se your answer, got it :)